# CLI Commands + Arguments are not executing correctly.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, command-line-interface

I`m working in the CLI commands in my Visual Studio C# application. This application does the interface with the Flash Programmer 2 (Texas Instruments Software to bootload the firmware in CC2560) using CLI ( Command-Line interface).
I checked some examples in StackOverflow, but I didn't have success to implement the solutions.

Steps of my application:

- *Select the serial port*
- *Open the console*
- *execute the srfprog.exe*
- *execute the command line (srfprog -t soc(COM84,CC2650) -e -p -v -f c:\test.bin )*
- *Check if the programming was a success*

My file is located in: D:\Projects\Test_Fixture\Test_Fixture_Visual_Studio\SmartRF Tools\Flash Programmer 2\bin\srfprog.exe
When I execute this in my CMD (windows) the Prompt window shows
[image]

After this screen pop up I sent the commands to program the chip

srfprog -t soc(COM84,CC2650) -e -p -v -f c:\test.bin
This command will program and verify the code in the microcontroller CC2650 as show in the screenshot below:

[image]

The programming is perfect.
However when I run(Click the button - Load Firmware) my application open and close Shell window immediately. As shown in the figure below
[image]

My code is below:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process CC2650 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        CC2650.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Projects\Test_Fixture\Test_Fixture_Visual_Studio\SmartRF Tools\Flash Programmer 2\bin\srfprog.exe";
        CC2650.StartInfo.Arguments = "srfprog -t soc(COM84,CC2650) -e -p -v -f c:\test.bin"; //argument
        CC2650.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        CC2650.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        CC2650.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        CC2650.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; //not diplay a windows
        CC2650.Start();
        string output = CC2650.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //The output result
        CC2650.WaitForExit();

    }
```

In this test I`m using the fixed COM port. Later I will select the port.

***Why my software is falling and doesn`t load the firmware?***
Thank you for your attention and time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be doubling up on *srfprog* by including it in the arguments. Filename defines the executable and Arguments should just be the stuff that comes after the Filename.

```
CC2650.StartInfo.Arguments = "-t soc(COM84,CC2650) -e -p -v -f c:\test.bin";
```

Comment: Dear Deepak, I tried  your suggestion and the software continue not working. The console pop up and close.  I tried              CC2650.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Projects\Test_Fixture\Test_Fixture_Visual_Studio\SmartRF Tools\Flash Programmer 2\bin\srfprog.exe";
            CC2650.StartInfo.Arguments = "-t soc(COM84,CC2650) -e -p -v -f c:\test.bin"; //argument

Comment: Deepak I tried: and              CC2650.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Projects\Test_Fixture\Test_Fixture_Visual_Studio\SmartRF Tools\Flash Programmer 2\bin";
            CC2650.StartInfo.Arguments = "srfprog -t soc(COM84,CC2650) -e -p -v -f c:\test.bin"; //argument in the second test the C# shows a message error (System.ComponentModel.win32exception: 'Access is denied'.

Comment: I'm guessing based on the button click event that this is running on an ASP.NET application? Unfortunately I'm not an expert there, so you'll need to research either granting permissions to the ASPNET account, or having the application run under different credentials. If you dump your code into a new console application, you should be able to at least rule out a problem with the code, and that should direct where you research next

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you don't need to pass the program name again in the arguments. To inspect what is happening please use code below. It will read the output and the errors in an async approach so we can analyse the output while the srfprog.exe is running. 
I don't have any C# compiler here so I could not test this code before writing here, maybe you will have to change something to make it work. Please try it and let my know what will be printed in your Visual Studio output console.

```
// Add "using System.Diagnostics;"
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = @"D:\Projects\Test_Fixture\Test_Fixture_Visual_Studio\SmartRF Tools\Flash Programmer 2\bin\srfprog.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "-t soc(COM84,CC2650) -e -p -v -f c:\test.bin";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
}

static void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
}
```